# How to properly exit from a custom blackhole handler?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My problem is fairly basic: whenever an action in CakePHP is blackholed, I want to display a custom error page; the default behaviour of Cake to display a "File not found" message confuses the hell out of users (not to mention developers). So I came up with this, by searching the docs and StackOverflow:

```
class TestsController extends AppController
{
  public $components = array ('Security');

  public function beforeFilter ()
  {
    parent::beforeFilter ();
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
    $this->Security->csrfExpires = '+5 seconds'; // for testing
  }

  public function index ()
  {

  }

  public function doit ()
  {
    $this->log ('Performing request; entry = ' . $this->data['foo'], 'tests');
    $this->set ('foo', $this->data['foo']);
  }

  public function blackhole ($type)
  {
    $this->log ('Request has been blackholed: ' . $type, 'tests');
    $this->render ('/Errors/blackhole');
    $this->response->send ();
    exit ();
  }
}
```

In index.ctp there is a simple form with a single textbox, that commits to `doit` (excluded for brevity). This works, **but** I have one major issue: the `exit()` in the blackhole() function. The problem is, if I do not exit here `doit()` is still called, even if the request is blackholed, as evidenced by the log:

```
2013-01-30 15:37:21 Tests: Request has been blackholed: csrf
2013-01-30 15:37:21 Tests: Performing request; entry = kfkfkfkf
```

This is clearly not what you expect. The Cake documentation hints at using (custom) exceptions to stop processing in blackhole(), but that:

- completely beats the purpose of using a custom handler;
- adds another layer of complexity to something that *should* be simple.

My question is: is there a proper way to do an "exit" from blackhole() so that Cake does all the rendering/cleanup/etc. that it usually does; I already had to add `$this->response->send()` to force output to the browser. Or, althernatively, a way to tell Cake to skip calling doit() after blackhole().

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to redirect in your blackhole.
This is done e.g. here in the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#usage

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index'));
```

A redirect will issue an exit (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control).
You can also send something nice to the user if you want, before the redirect:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('What are you doing!?');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blackhole callback you could just throw an exception with required message. That would render the proper error page and get logged too (assuming you have turned on logging for errors in core.php).

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want. Throwing an exception will use the default Cake error message views, while I want to display a custom page. I could use my own Exception class + handler, but as I wrote before, I consider that needlessly complex.

Comment: So customize the default error views. You can also use your own exceptions and custom ExceptionRender for rendering error view for your exception.